# jpa entity not found exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following problems:
The class Foo is an EntityBean with a List of Item.

```
  public class Foo {
    @OneToMany(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>()
```

At some point in my application I do the following:

1. remove item with id 3 from the lsit of foo
2. call updateFoo()

---

```
@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateFoo(Foo foo){
   if(item has been removed from the list of foo){
      //item is from the List of the parameter foo
      entityManager.remove(item);
    }
      entityManager.flush();

     //update remaining items 
     for(Item item: foo.getItems()){
        //set some field values on item
        ...
        entityManager.merge(item);
       }        

    //here occurs the exception
    entityManager.merge(foo);  
  }
```

Everything does work fine until the last line is executed. Then the exception

```
 javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Item with id 3.
```

Best regards

Edmond

Comment: Does `Item` have a relation to `Foo`?

Comment: No. It is a uni-directional relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the relation bidirectional, comment out the call to flush and finally add merge, persist and remove as cascade type.

Answer (score 0):

You should manually remove the item from the collection before executing the entityManager.remove.